# Alfresco Bulk Import Tool

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

Has anyone used Alfresco Bulk import tool, can you please help me with pro and cons. 
What was the size of data you were trying to migrate and speed

Answer (score 1):

It's the best way to import into Alfresco, especially if you're not keen on developing something on your own, and/or paying for a third party service.

Be sure to use the "pmonks" version of it, and not the one shipped with Alfresco.
https://github.com/pmonks/alfresco-bulk-import

The size of data and speed varies greatly on your setup: How many batches, how large is the batch size, number of threads, how deep is your folder structure, memory available and so on. But in general, I've migrated TBs and millions with it.

Comment: Does it works with S3 storage or is it only with local storage as content repository?

Comment: BIT doesn't care about storage, that part is up to Alfresco. If S3 works while working normally with Alfresco/Share, it will work with BIT, too.